# Out of range error - merge sort algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, mergesort

I am trying to implement the merge sort algorithm using the following code but am getting a list index is out of range error.

```
def mergeSort (unSortedList):
if len(unSortedList) == 1 :
    return unSortedList
else:
    midpoint = len(unSortedList)//2
    A = mergeSort (unSortedList[:midpoint] )
    B = mergeSort (unSortedList[midpoint:] )
    i = 0
    j = 0
    C = []
    for k in range(len(unSortedList)):
        if A[i] >= B[j]:
            C.append(A[i])
            if i == len(A):
                C.append(B[j:])
            else:
                i += 1
        elif A[i] < B[j] :
            C.append(B[j])
            if j == len(B):
                C.append(A[i:])
            else:
                j += 1
    return C
testlist = [2,1,4,2,5,6,8,9]
print (mergeSort(testlist))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you extract the `merge` procedure to an extra function. It will be more readable and clear what it does: merge and sort.

Comment: You should get your indentation right.. (and post the error).

Comment: you're out by one on your conditionals here: if i == len(A):  should be if i == len(A) -1:  and your next problem is don't add lists like this: C.append(A[i:]) add them like this: C += A[i:]

Comment: Also (this looks like homework of some sort).. but for anyone browsing here there's built in list sorting in python e.g. see here https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version of your `mergeSort`, with the `merge` function extracted:

```
def mergeSort (unSortedList):
    if len(unSortedList) == 1 :
        return unSortedList
    else:
        midpoint = len(unSortedList)//2
        A = mergeSort (unSortedList[:midpoint] )
        B = mergeSort (unSortedList[midpoint:] )
        return merge(A, B)

def merge(a, b):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    c = []
    while True:
        if a[i] < b[j]:
            c.append(b[j])
            j += 1
        elif a[i] >= b[j]:
            c.append(a[i])
            i += 1

        if i == len(a):
            c.extend(b[j:])
            break
        if j == len(b):
            c.extend(a[i:])
            break
    return c
```

Output:

```
>>> testlist = [2,1,4,2,5,6,8,9]
>>> mergeSort(testlist)
[9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1]
```

Couple of things to note:

1. **Appending a list to a list.** When you do `C.append(A[j:])` you end up with nested lists. That is because `A[j:]` always returns a list. You either need to use list addition - `C += A[j:]` - or call `extend` - `C.extend(A[j:])`
2. **Missing breaks.** When your `i` or `j` got to the end of their lists you correctly appended the rest of the other list but you did not terminate the loop. That is what caused the range error because in the next iteration (which should not happen) you tried to get an item at the index equal to the length of the list which is out of range.

Comment: Great, Thank you ! The list addition method is much simpler.